# How do I get the data from my Controller to my View using json_encode?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get the data from my Controller and access it to my view. I want to try encoding the data as I send it to my View. Here's what I have been doing so far.

controller.php

```
if($survey = $this->survey->get($survey_id, $user, $page_no, $items_per_page)) {
   echo json_encode(array("survey" => $survey, "status_message" => "Survey has been fetched", "status" => true, "status_code" => 2));
   }
```

I want to pass the `$survey` data to my View so that i can access it's elements.

model.php

```
function get($survey_id, $user, $page_no, $items_per_page) {

    .
    .
    .
    .
     $questions = $this->get_questions(null, $survey_id, $page_no, $items_per_page);
     $num_of_questions = $this->get_question_number(null, $survey_id);
     $total_page = ceil($num_of_questions/$items_per_page);

     $survey['items'] = $questions;
     $survey['total_page'] = $total_page;
     $survey['page_group'] = $page_no;
     $survey['survey_id'] = $survey_id;
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

now in my view.php, I want something like:

view.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var survey_id = json_decode(survey[survey_id]);
 .
 .
 .
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need json_encode for that. You can use direct array to the view.

Controller.php

```
$data['survey']="";
if($survey = $this->survey->get($survey_id, $user, $page_no, $items_per_page)) {
    $data['survey']=$servey;
}
$this->load->view('your_view_name',$data);
```

View.php

`print_r($survey);`

Comment: Thank you for that @Disha but, i already know that. I just want to try sending data using json_encode. :D

Comment: Oh, then you can use `$data['survey']=json_encode($survey)` and decode it to the view if you want to use.

Comment: can't I use `echo json_encode(array("survey" => $survey, "status_message" => "Survey has been fetched", "status" => true, "status_code" => 2));` instead of loading the view?

Comment: Yes, what's the issue?